# Get dice game to play again if user chooses to in c#

Tags: c#

I've struggled through a uni assignment to create a dice game. I've finished it but of course forgot to add the option to replay the game if necessary and am so lost in code that I don't even know where to being to get the game to play again. I would really appreciate some help to be able to get users to play another game if they want to or escape the console app.

```
     using System;

public class Player {

  private int score;
  private string name;
  private bool isAI = false;

  public void reset() {
    this.score = 0;
  }

  public void addScore(int scoreToAdd) {
    this.score = this.score + scoreToAdd;
  }

  public int getScore() {
    return this.score;
  }

  public string getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(string name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  /// Prompt the player to 'roll the dice'
  public void prompt() {
    if (isAI) { return; }
    Console.WriteLine(getName() + ", please roll the dice (press enter):");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  public void promptForName() {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name (Enter 'cpu' to play against the computer)");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    setName(name);
    // special handling for computer players.
    if (name == "cpu") { isAI = true; }
    else { isAI = false; }
  }

  public void printScore() {
    Console.WriteLine(name + " score: " + this.score);
  }

  public int playRound(Random rnd, Die d1, Die d2, Die d3) {
    // Prompt the player so the dice don't roll immediately
    this.prompt();

    // Roll all the dice (pass the same rng for each one)
    d1.roll(rnd);
    d2.roll(rnd);
    d3.roll(rnd);

    // Work out which dice is highest, roll the smaller 2 again
    if (d1.getValue() > d2.getValue() && d1.getValue() > d3.getValue()) {
      d2.roll(rnd);
      d3.roll(rnd);
      // Work out which is the highest of the two re-rolled, then roll the
      // smallest a third time
      if (d2.getValue() > d3.getValue()) {
        d3.roll(rnd);
      }
      else {
        d2.roll(rnd);
      }
    }
    else if (d2.getValue() > d1.getValue() && d2.getValue() > d3.getValue()) {
      d1.roll(rnd);
      d3.roll(rnd);
      // Work out which is the highest of the two re-rolled, then roll the
      // smallest a third time
      if (d1.getValue() > d3.getValue()) {
        d3.roll(rnd);
      }
      else {
        d1.roll(rnd);
      }
    }
    else {
      d1.roll(rnd);
      d2.roll(rnd);
      // Work out which is the highest of the two re-rolled, then roll the
      // smallest a third time
      if (d1.getValue() > d2.getValue()) {
        d2.roll(rnd);
      }
      else {
        d1.roll(rnd);
      }
    }

    // All dice are rolled, just calculate total
    int total = d1.getValue() + d2.getValue() + d3.getValue();

    return total;
  }

}


public class Die
{

    private int value;

    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void roll(Random rnd)
    {
        this.value = rnd.Next(1, 7);
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public static string promptForPlayType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter play type ('match' or 'score')");
        string playType = null;
        // Make sure the user enters a valid value
        while (playType != "match" && playType != "score")
        {
            playType = Console.ReadLine();
            if (playType != "match" && playType != "score")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter one of the two options");
            }
        }

        return playType;
    }

    // Entry point
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Prompt the user for the game play type they'd want (match or score)
        string playType = promptForPlayType();

        // Create rng, need this because otherwise the seed gets re-initialised to
        // the same value each time
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Create the players & prompt for their names
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        p1.promptForName();
        p2.promptForName();

        // Create the 3 dice we'll be using
        Die d1 = new Die();
        Die d2 = new Die();
        Die d3 = new Die();

        // The big 'game loop' where everything happens
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i = i + 1)
        {
            // Basically everything happens in these method calls
            var p1Result = p1.playRound(rnd, d1, d2, d3);
            var p2Result = p2.playRound(rnd, d1, d2, d3);

            // Increment score based on result
            if (playType == "match")
            {
                if (p1Result > p2Result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p1.getName() + " won a round");
                    p1.addScore(1);
                }
                else if (p2Result > p1Result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p2.getName() + " won a round");
                    p2.addScore(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Game drawn");
                }
            }
            else if (playType == "score")
            {
                p1.addScore(p1Result);
                p2.addScore(p2Result);
            }

            // Print out running totals
            Console.WriteLine("Player scores:");
            Console.WriteLine(p1.getName() + ": " + p1.getScore());
            Console.WriteLine(p2.getName() + ": " + p2.getScore());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        if (p1.getScore() > p2.getScore())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 won");
        }
        else if (p2.getScore() > p1.getScore())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2 won");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The game was a draw");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you expect us to go through your entire program and add a feature for you? if you wrote it, surely you must have some idea about how to implement it. maybe have a go by yourself and then come back with a more specific question

Comment: So basically you want to **do** { some stuff } **while** ( the user chooses to keep playing ) (brackets added to make it more obvious that simply formally stating what you want to do in the right way is about half-way to having the code)? It sounds simple enough to write code for that, what specific problem are you having doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose it in while loop until users exit from it.

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool flag = true;
    while(flag){

        //your game here

        Console.WriteLine("Play again? ('y' or 'n')");
        string playAgain = null;
        playAgain = Console.ReadLine();
        if(playAgain == "n")
            flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, I presume then I can just call

     public void reset() {
     this.score = 0;
     }

and put everything inside the loop you described above.